# app status is inactive after being uploaded to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i clicked "ready to submit",and the status has already been "waiting for review"
what is the meaning of this in Prerelease? the app status is inactive
[image]

and there is another app,the status is Processing

[image]

they are both in "waiting for review" !what is the different? is there something wrong?

Comment: did you find any luck on this because I have same issue

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara nothing changes~ my app is still during "waiting for review",maybe we should ignore it

Comment: Yes ignore that thing

Answer (score 0):

They are preparing the review as far as I know. just ignore it